# Elements don't appear in a Panel with a GridLayout or FlowLayout, but with a setBounds they do

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm doing a program that is composed by multiple panels in a JFrame.
I need to do every elements in differents classes (It's because in my school, we need to have every elements separeated in different classes for clean code), but every example that I see with my kind of problem, they do everything in one class.
And I think that my problem comes from having multile classes so I show you my classes.

I have a panel in wich I need to put 2 panel, here is the code :

```
public class Inscription extends JPanel{
private PanneauBoutons panneauBoutons = new PanneauBoutons();
private PanneauFormulaire panneauFormulaire = new PanneauFormulaire();

  public Inscription(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));

    this.add(panneauFormulaire,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panneauBoutons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setVisible(true);
  }  
}
```

And here is the Panel panneauFormulaire :

```
public class PanneauFormulaire extends JPanel{
private JLabel labelMatricule;
private JTextField zoneTexteMatricule;

public PanneauFormulaire(){
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2,10,10));

    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    labelMatricule = new JLabel("Matricule : ");
    this.add(labelMatricule);
    zoneTexteMatricule = new JTextField(30);
    this.add(zoneTexteMatricule);

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

So the problem Inscription don't appear on the main Frame if I don't do setBounds, but I want a BorderLayout...
(I tested and with a set bounds I can see the borders, so I think that it means the panel are really added to the Frame so why without setBounds I see anything?).
And the other problem is that the panel PanneauFormulaire don't appear on the Inscription panel...

So if I miss something, can you help me? thank you

And here it is the class that extends JFrame :

```
public class FenetrePrincipale extends JFrame {
  private Container cont;
  private Inscription inscriptionForm;

  public FenetrePrincipale(){
    super("IESN");
    setBounds(100,100,1200,960);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    ...

    inscription.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cont.removeAll();

            inscriptionForm = new Inscription();
            inscriptionForm.setOpaque(true);

            cont.add(inscriptionForm);

            invalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"And here it is the class that extends JFrame :"* You say that like it should (extend frame, instead of simply using an instance of one).

Comment: *"I need to do every elements in differents classes,"* Why? *"but every example that I see with my kind of problem, they do everything in one class."* That might be because the author of the code is trying to make a [mcve] showing how to do something specific. Note that technically an MCVE ***can*** have more than one class, but if it needs to, the classes with no `main(String[])` method are typically reduced to default access (i.e. not `public`) and pasted in at the end of the source with a main method. The idea is to show others how to do something specific - it does not need to be ..

Comment: .. well 'designed' code to do that. The reader is expected to be able to look through the example and *understand* what is going on, so they can then adapt it to their own (presumably larger, with more classes) code base.

Comment: Do you adding the `cont` to the your frame? What is its layout?

Comment: if by adding cont you mean that : cont = getContentPane(); yes I do

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT be using a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

> but when I click on an option in the menu, the current panel need to be change by another one,

Then you should be using a `CardLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for working examples. So download the example and use it as the starting point of your project. The code will be better structured then what you currently have and it is easier to change working code than it is to fix broken code.

Answer (score 1):

> so why without setBounds I see anything?

That is because you set your layout to `null` in `getContentPane().setLayout(null);`.

Java containers comes with a default layout which you are allowed to set to a different one. How the components are arranged in the container are dependent on the layout you use. The layout will directly affects the location, alignment, spacing, dimension, preferredSize of the components.

However, if you choose not to use any layout (`.setLayout(null)`). Swing will not know how you want the components to be arranged, hence you see nothing in your content pane.

Since you wanted "absolute control" over the components, you will be expected to set the bounds (location and dimension) of each added component ***manually*** by yourself. This is why you are not seeing any components (even if you already added it) until you set the bounds for them.

> Java, elements don't appear in a Panel with a GridLayout or FlowLayout, but with a setBounds they do

Every layout has their own characteristics and for some of them the order of your codes does makes a difference. Hence, I will advise you to go through what each layout can do for you. Then, depending on your needs, choose one (or a combination of a few) and study how to use it.

> And here it is the class that extends JFrame :

You probably won't want to extends to a JFrame. You can always make a customized Container like JPanel and add it to the frame.

*(Why would you want to paint your paintings on a frame instead of a piece of paper?)*